# Partial Threaded Sorting in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sorting

I'm trying to do a partial sort with a threads,
my current output it

```
27 12 21 48 15 28 82 69 35 91 
13 82 33 35 46 5 35 28 87 95 
0 10 20 22 23 30 52 80 86 96 
3 8 42 53 67 70 70 71 75 79 
5 8 8 18 41 43 70 79 86 88 
10 51 56 60 65 84 87 91 94 99 
23 25 38 39 40 44 51 56 69 75 
20 21 25 29 29 38 66 71 73 96 
33 50 9 6 13 27 97 21 70 22 
3 4 6 6 7 15 34 59 63 70
```

As you can see I am getting it partially sorted I want my output to be this (no merging at the end)

```
12 15 21 27 28 35 48 69 82 91 
5 13 28 33 35 35 46 82 87 95 
0 10 20 22 23 30 52 80 86 96 
3 8 42 53 67 70 70 71 75 79 
5 8 8 18 41 43 70 79 86 88 
10 51 56 60 65 84 87 91 94 99 
23 25 38 39 40 44 51 56 69 75 
20 21 25 29 29 38 66 71 73 96 
6 9 13 21 22 27 33 50 70 97 
3 4 6 6 7 15 34 59 63 70
```

I can get the right output if instead of using a struct I use &array[i] and manually input the length

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

struct values {
    int *arrayptr;
    int length;
};

void *thread_fn(void *a) {
    struct values *start = a;

    qsort(start->arrayptr, start->length, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
    return (void*)a;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {      
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[3], "r");
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("numS1.dat", "w+");

    //amount of threads
    int threadAmount = atoi(argv[1]);
    //size of input
    int numberAmount = atoi(argv[2]);

    //multidimensional array
    int array[threadAmount][numberAmount / threadAmount];

    for (int i = 0; i < threadAmount; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < numberAmount / threadAmount; j++)
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &array[i][j]);

    pthread_t threadid[threadAmount];

    for (int i = 0; i < threadAmount; ++i) {
        struct values a = { array[i], numberAmount / threadAmount };

        pthread_create(&threadid[i], NULL, thread_fn, &a);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < threadAmount; ++i)
        pthread_join(threadid[i], NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < threadAmount; i++) {
        if (i != 0)
            fprintf(fp1, "\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < numberAmount / threadAmount; j++)
            fprintf(fp1 ,"%d ", array[i][j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Do you know where I am going wrong?
I think its the struct but everything I see online does what I'm doing.

Comment: stack overflow is no debugging or code review service. See [ask]

Comment: welcome to the fun phase of sw development. did u try using a debugger?

Comment: You're passing a pointer to `a` to the thread. Then `a` gets destroyed immediately, because it's a local variable that goes out of scope. Then some time later the thread actually starts, and looks at the space where `a` used to be.

Comment: allocate the struct (using malloc) and let the thread free it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, Malloc, something i've totally forgotten since i've been using Java almost exclusively the last 8 months thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to automatic storage to newly created threads: the `struct values` object becomes invalid as soon as the calling scope is exited, thus it cannot be reliably accessed by the new thread.  You should allocate the `struct values` and pass the pointer to the allocated object as a parameter to `pthread_create`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadAmount; ++i) {
    struct values *a = malloc(sizeof(*a));

    a->arrayptr = array[i];
    a->length = numberAmount / threadAmount;

    pthread_create(&threadid[i], NULL, thread_fn, a);
}
```

The structure can be freed by the thread function before exiting.

Notes:

- the way you split the array into chunks only works if the length is a multiple of the number of threads.
- the comparison function does not work for large `int` values, you should use this instead:

  ```
  int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
      return (*(int*)b < *(int*)a) - (*(int*)a < *(int*)b);
  }
  ```

Comment: Okay thanks!!. The malloc was what was wrong. I'll also change the comparison function too.